# Flatten a dynamic hierarchy tree by level

Tags: java, recursion, tree, hierarchy, flatten

I have a hierarchy tree that I retrieve on the fly (via REST services). I limit the data based on a depth and a limit of data I want. I want to flatten that tree based on the level, so first the children then the grandchildren, etc.

For example:

```
1
 -2
   -4
   -5
     -8
 -3
   -6
   -7
     -9
```

With a depth 100 and limit 100 it should be 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
With a depth 1 and limit 100 it should be 2 3
with a depth 2 and ​limit 5 it should be 2 3 4 5 6

Right now ​I have a recursive algorithm but it doesn't flatten by level but recursively (2 4 5 8 3 6 7 9).
Here is the actual code:

```
@GET
@Path("/GetDatas")
public Response getDatas(@QueryParam("clientId") final String clientId,
                           @QueryParam("maxDepth") final Integer maxDepth,
                           @QueryParam("limit") final Integer limit) {

    Set datas = new LinkedHashSet();

    findChildren(clientId, maxDepth, limit, datas, 0);

    return Response.status(Response.Status.OK).entity(datas).build();
}

private void findChildren(String clientId, Integer maxDepth, Integer limit, Set datas, Integer actualDepth)  {
    // here we are getting the data via a REST WS
    results = .... (function(clientId))

    for (final String result : results) {
        if (datas.size() < limit) {
            if (!datas.contains(result)) {
                datas.add(result);
                if (actualDepth < maxDepth) {
                    findChildren(result, maxDepth, limit, datas, actualDepth + 1);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I simplified a little bit. In fact, in reality a node will have himself as a grandchild too (the getChildren will retrieve matching datas based on a algorithm, so if 2 is a match for 1, 1 is the match for 2).

The order of the list is also important.

Here is the JDoodle so you can test:
[jdoodle.com/ia/gFm](https://jdoodle.com/ia/gFm)

Comment: I'm not sure if it is the whole problem or not, but it looks to me like you need a breadth first rather than a depth first.

Comment: What `results` contains is unclear, json or List? I suggest you give an example of `results` in the code. And what does `findMatches` do?

Comment: findMatches was an error, it's findChildren.
results is normally a json object with a list but for simplification purpose, consider it as a list ([2, 3])

Comment: You can apply Breadth First Search. For more help post [mre]. Include hard-coded test data.

Comment: Can you show a concrete, specific data structure input (test case) with sample output? It's hard to tell what's going on here otherwise. The fact that you're fetching data and working with a response is irrelevant, just hardcode some sample data we can actually work with, please.

Comment: Side notes:  findChildren signature is `findChildren(String clientId, Integer maxDepth, Integer limit, Set datas, Integer actualDepth)`.  `clientId` is never used in the method and the recursive call uses a different name: `findChildren(result, maxDepth, limit, datas, actualDepth + 1);`. Also use 'int` rather than `Integer` where possible.

Comment: ClientId is used in the results = .... I didn't want to put the whole code here.
A typical response from the web service would be like:
[
    "2",
    "3",
    "4"
]

Comment: I just added a JDoodle with the test code...

Comment: This is, as has been previously-noted, a case where you want to traverse your tree breadth-first rather than depth first. Moreover, you seem to be making an API call for *every* call to findChildren(). This is unnecessary and substantially slower than making that call just once in getDatas()

Comment: @JamesS. I can't and won't retrieve all the datas because there is billions of entities. That's why there is a depth and limit to not load the whole data (45Go) each time.

Comment: That makes significantly more sense. Still, you really want to traverse your tree breadth-first. Basically, you want to build your list from nodes that you dequeue until you hit either limit or maxdepth, and then print the list.

Comment: **_I didn't want to put the whole code here_** this is not required.  [mre] is required. Please don't link code but post it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following mre uses [BFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search) to flatten the tree, respecting the limits:

```
import java.util.*;

public class MyClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new DataClass().execute();
    }

    static class DataClass {

        public void execute() {

            Map<String, List<String>> tree = new LinkedHashMap();

            tree.put("1", Arrays.asList("2", "3"));
            tree.put("2", Arrays.asList("4", "5"));
            tree.put("3", Arrays.asList("6", "7"));
            tree.put("5", Arrays.asList("8"));
            tree.put("7", Arrays.asList("9"));
            tree.put("4", Arrays.asList());
            tree.put("6", Arrays.asList());
            tree.put("8", Arrays.asList());
            tree.put("9", Arrays.asList());

            int maxDepth =100, maxNodes =100;
            System.out.println("max depth:"+ maxDepth + " max nodes:"+ maxNodes +" - "+ findChildren(maxDepth, maxNodes, tree));

            maxDepth =1; maxNodes =100;
            System.out.println("max depth:"+ maxDepth + " max nodes:"+ maxNodes +" - "+ findChildren(maxDepth, maxNodes, tree));

            maxDepth =2; maxNodes =5;
            System.out.println("max depth:"+ maxDepth + " max nodes:"+ maxNodes +" - "+findChildren(maxDepth, maxNodes, tree));
        }

        //helper method for bfs
        Set<String> findChildren(int maxDepth, int maxNodes,  Map<String, List<String>> tree)  {
            Set<String> flatTree = new LinkedHashSet<>(); //hold and return the flatten tree
            final String root = "1";
            List<String> nodesAtCurrentDepth = new ArrayList<>();//hold all nodes of the current depth
            nodesAtCurrentDepth.add(root);
            return findChildren(maxDepth,  maxNodes, 0, flatTree, nodesAtCurrentDepth, tree);
        }

        //flatten tree using bfs
        Set<String> findChildren(int maxDepth, int maxNodes, int currentDepth, Set<String> flatTree,
                List<String> nodesAtCurrentDepth, Map<String, List<String>> tree)  {

            if(currentDepth < maxDepth && ! nodesAtCurrentDepth.isEmpty()) {

                List<String> nodesAtNextDepth = new ArrayList<>();//collects all next level nodes
                //add all next depth nodes to nodesAtNextDepth, respecting maxNodes limit
                for(String node : nodesAtCurrentDepth){

                    for(String childNode : tree.get(node)){
                        if(flatTree.size() + nodesAtNextDepth.size() >= maxNodes) {
                            break;
                        }
                        nodesAtNextDepth.add(childNode);
                    }
                }

                flatTree.addAll(nodesAtNextDepth);
                currentDepth++;
                nodesAtCurrentDepth = new ArrayList<>(nodesAtNextDepth);
                findChildren(maxDepth,  maxNodes, currentDepth, flatTree, nodesAtCurrentDepth, tree);
            };

            return flatTree;
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

> max depth:100 max nodes:100 - [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
>  max depth:1
> max nodes:100 - [2, 3]
>  max depth:2 max nodes:5 - [2, 3, 4, 5,
> 6]

Comment: I add to change some parts (for example to not readd a node that was already in the list) but globally it does the job. 
Thanks a lot.

Comment: _"not readd a node that was already in the list"_ all nodes at a certain depth are added once only so I don't think it is necessary here